# Devexpress grid slow reponse after idle

Tags: asp.net, iis, devexpress, iis-7.5, devexpress-windows-ui

I'm using devexpress gridview on developing application that users have to view group of row data,my application works fine on development server of visual studio 2010 but when i deploy the application on iis 7.5 performance issue become clear.
when page is loaded on IE for the first time ,application respond normally and ajax calls respond fine,but when  application became idle for awhile*(approximately less than 5 minutes)* ,ajax calls responding issue appear (takes 20 seconds for a single request).

note that:

-i review all application pool configurations on iis.

-i notice that when i use Firefox application respond normally but unfortunately i need to use it on IE. 
-when i deploy the application locally from my machine (Local IIS) application respond normally.

could any one help please

Answer (score 1):

If you're saying that the response time in Firefox is good then the issue is not IIS.
Devexpress controls are heavy on client (javascript) and can cause delays in page loading (especially if you use jQuery)

I suggest to:

- create a test page that has nothing other than the gridview on it.
- Enable client script debugging (in IE options)
- use IE developer Profiler to see any client errors

Comment: me too think so but since devexpress controls are heavy why my page works fine on first load and behave on bad way after idle,i guess there is timeout(session,cashe,iis,...) somewhere but i cant determine exactly where this problem came from

Comment: @MamadoJoseph there could be multiple reasons. Do you have update panel on page? if you use IE developer Profiler (click Start profiling) and then do the 2nd load (postback) and you'll see what is send back to the server and how long it takes to come back, how large it is to download, also check [Console] tab to see any errors.

Comment: Yes im using update panel and the grid view is lied over it.but why you have doubt on it however I will remove it the update panel and run the page with the grid .regarding profiling I will check anf feedyou back with the results